# SharePoint 2007 Export list to excel - 'person or group' column as domain\username

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, export

I have SharePoint 2007 list that has 'person or group' field, lets call it employee.
When I export this list to excel, I get the column values as display name 'firstname + lastname (Joe Blog), what I need is domain\username.
I need this so I can import the list to newer version of SharePoint (2013).

I can achieve the above by going to employee column in sp2007 and change the show filed type to Account, and then do the export to Excel.

But there must be a way of doing this without changing the show filed type for the column.

May be editing the owssvr.iqy file to include domain\username instead of default display name.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to list settings
   Select the required field
   [image: 01]
2. Change "Show field" to "Account"
   [image: 02]
3. Check how it looks in the browser:
   [image: 03]
4. Export as usual and check:
   [image: 04]

Comment: Hi Sergey
Please see my question..
"I can achieve the above by going to employee column in sp2007 and change the show filed type to Account, and then do the export to Excel."

But this is live system and I DO NOT really want to do this, there must be another way.